# Very special kind of AVG statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table example:

```
time  a  b  c
-------------
12:00  1  0  1
12:00  2  3  1
13:00  3  2  1
13:00  3  3  3
14:00  1  1  1
```

How can I get `AVG(a)` from row `WHERE b!=0` and `AVG(c)` grouped by time. Is it possible to solve with `sql` only? I mean that query should not count 1st row to get `AVG(a)`, but not the same with `AVG(c)`.

Comment: You should probably give the expected results as well. I feel like there's something missing from your description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `CASE` statements to get conditional aggregates:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN b != 0 THEN a END)
      ,AVG(c)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY time
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/612f6/8/0)

This works because a value not captured by `WHEN` criteria in a `CASE` statement will default to `NULL`, and `NULL` values are ignored by aggregate functions.

Comment: Seems very nice. I'm going to test this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(a), AVG(c) from table WHERE b != 0
group by time
```

Yea... is this what you need?

Comment: `AVG(c) ` is in the question as well

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like

```
SELECT T.tTIME
, AVG(CASE WHEN T.B != 0 THEN T.A END)
, AVG(T.C)

FROM @T T


GROUP BY T.tTIME
```

The output is the following:

```
tTIME   (No column name)    (No column name)
12:00:00.0000000    2   1
13:00:00.0000000    3   2
14:00:00.0000000    1   1
```

Comment: You might want to remove the non-standard stuff as the above will not work in Postgres